# Printing Right Triangles w/ Nested For-Loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

Here's my loop:

```cs
int height = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Printing a " + height + " by " + height + " right triangle...");

for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("*");
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
    }
```

And here is the resulting print (program takes a user input for the height, this example has a height of 5:

```
*
**
***
****
****
```

As you can see, I can't get the last star to print on the last row. This makes absolutely no sense to me, as I've compared it to many other similar constructs and there appears to be no discrepancies between the one I've constructed and the ones others have made. I just started coding about a month ago so I'm still a greenhorn.

Comment: This output is produced for a `4`. For a `5`, there are six lines in the output. This is because `WriteLine` is called five times, which makes six lines.

Answer (score 0):

`WriteLine` implicitly adds a newline to the end of the string. `Write` will not. Follow each step in each iteration of the two loops to find the bug. For the first iteration, when `i` is 1, you get:

```
*       <-- WriteLine (i == 1), adds a newline
*       <-- Write (i == 1, j == 1), does not add a newline! Next character will be printed after this * on the same line!
```

Now follow what happens when `i` is 2:

```
*       <-- WriteLine (i == 1)
**      <-- Write (i == 1, j == 1), followed by WriteLine (i == 2) on the same line
**      <-- Write (i == 2, j == 1), followed by Write (i == 2, j == 2)
```

Do you see where the bug is? You're printing the newline character in the middle of the current row; you should be printing it at the end of the row instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're doing a `Console.WriteLine()` first, followed by the `Console.Write()`, which means that for each iteration it's writing on two different lines.

To fix this, you can just add a `WriteLine()` to the end of the loop, so that you `Write()` each star for a row, then `WriteLine()` so the next iteration begins the next row on the next line:

```
// For each row
for (int row = 1; row <= height; row++)
{
    // For each column in the row
    for (int col = 1; col <= row; col++)
    {
        // Write a star
        Console.Write("*");
    }

    // End the row
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

---

Note that there's an overload to the `string` constructor that allows you to specify a character and the number of times it should be repeated to create the string. This can come in handy here, allowing us to remove the inner loop:

```
// For each row
for (int row = 1; row <= height; row++)
{
    // Write a string with 'row' number of stars
    Console.WriteLine(new string('*', row));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, the issue is with the *Console.WriteLine("*")*. If you count the amount of rows being produced after running your code segment, you will find that there is an extra row each time.
Running your code segment with a height of 5 will actually produce 6 rows of stars:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
*****
```

This is because before you even enter the inner loop, you are printing a star and then starting a new line.
To simplify this, it is best to assign each loop with a role, the inner loop should be the one outputting the stars. The outer loop is responsible for printing the new line.

Here is what I came up with. I modified the for loops to use the variables row and col. I find it much easier to comprehend.

```
for (int row = 1; row <= height; row++) {
   for (int col = 1; col <= row; col++){
      Console.Write("*");
   }
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Apparently we think alike. :)

Comment: @RufusL Yep, looks like it haha

Comment: I see. I was printing an extra star with each row because every int i prints another star. thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

What looping operation would be complete without at least one `LINQ` solution? Ok, here you go:

```
    private static void TestRightAngle(int height)
    {
        var l = new int[height];
        int i = 0;
        l.ToList().ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine(string.Empty.PadRight(++i, '*')));
    }
```

Yes, it's gratuitous and it's inefficient, but it does have that "Je Ne Sais Quoi"...it has that `LINQ`-appeal.